# Geom_line not plotting colors correctly for characters but fine for numerics

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I'm confused. Say I have the following data:

```
require("ggplot2")

treatment=c(rep("NO", 10), rep("YES", 30), c(rep("NO", 10)),
            rep("YES", 10), rep("NO", 30), c(rep("YES", 10)))

dat=data.frame(time=rep(1:50, 2), group=rep(c("GROUP 1", "GROUP 2"),     each=50), treatment=treatment)
```

Why does this not work:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=time, y=group, color=treatment))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

But this works (group 2's colors change correctly)?

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=time, y=group, color=as.numeric(as.factor(treatment))))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: You are plotting `geom_line()`, which connects each categorical value in the first graph and each point in the second.  In the first graph, "Yes" is plotted on top of "No", and a line extends from point 10 to point 41. Try `geom_point()` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `group=group` clause to the `aes` function to get what you want, othewise it doesn't handle the factors correctly:

```
require("ggplot2")

treatment=c(rep("NO", 10), rep("YES", 30), c(rep("NO", 10)),
            rep("YES", 10), rep("NO", 30), c(rep("YES", 10)))

dat=data.frame(time=rep(1:50, 2), group=rep(c("GROUP 1", "GROUP 2")
                                            each=50), treatment=treatment)


ggplot(dat, aes(x=time, y=group, color=treatment,group=group))+  
  geom_line()+ labs(title="Group")
```

[image]